# efficient way of sumproduct at row level based on column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat below (please note There are columns beyond COST and UNITS)

```
TIME      COST1   UNITS1_1   COST2   UNITS2_1   ....  COSTN  UNITSN_1 
21:55:51  25      100        20       50        ....   22    130
22:55:51  23      100        24       150        ....   22    230
21:58:51  28      100        22       250        ....   22    430
```

I am looking at computing a sumproduct (New column) for each row such that (COST1*UNITS1_1) +  (COST2*UNITS2_1) + (COSTN*UNITSN_1) is computed and stored in this column

Could you advise an efficient way here.
The ones that am thinking are looping through the column names based on the filter condition for the columns and /or using a lambda function to compute the necessary number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select columns by positions, convert to numpy array by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) or [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), multiple them and last sum:

```
#pandas 0.24+
df['new'] = (df.iloc[:, ::2].to_numpy() * df.iloc[:, 1::2].to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)
#pandas lower
#df['new'] = (df.iloc[:, ::2].values * df.iloc[:, 1::2].values).sum(axis=1)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for select columns:

```
df['new'] = (df.filter(like='COST').to_numpy()*df.filter(like='UNITS').to_numpy()).sum(axis=1)

df['new'] = (df.filter(like='COST').values*df.filter(like='UNITS').values).sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
          COST1  UNITS1_1  COST2  UNITS2_1  COSTN  UNITSN_1    new
TIME                                                              
21:55:51     25       100     20        50     22       130   6360
22:55:51     23       100     24       150     22       230  10960
21:58:51     28       100     22       250     22       430  17760
```

Comment: Can you help to explain what it is doing exactly..
to_numpy() seems new ?

Comment: @asimo - yes, it convet DataFrame to numpy array, alternative is `.values`